# Uglify not working with Grunt Watch

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have a pretty basic setup with sass, watch and uglify but for some reason I can't get watch to detect when a js file is saved. It works fine for SCSS/CSS (compiles and reloads.) If I run 'grunt uglify' it bundles my JS files, and if watch is running (in another console instance) it will detect it and trigger the reload.

I've tried lots of combinations and I have a feeling it's something really dumb I'm doing/not doing but I'm just not seeing it.

my gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass', 'uglify']);
  grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: { 'fivesixtwo.com/src/FiveSixTwo.com/wwwroot/css/main.css': 'fivesixtwo.com/src/FiveSixTwo.com/wwwroot/css/main.scss' }
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      my_target: {
        files: {
          'fivesixtwo.com/src/FiveSixTwo.com/wwwroot/js/site.js': [
            'fivesixtwo.com/src/FiveSixTwo.com/wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            'fivesixtwo.com/src/FiveSixTwo.com/wwwroot/lib/*.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      options: {
        livereload: 35729,
      },
      html: {
        files: ['fivesixtwo.com/src/FiveSixTwo.com/Views/*.cshtml'],
      },
      sass: {
        options: {
          livereload: false
        },
        files: ['fivesixtwo.com/src/FiveSixTwo.com/wwwroot/css/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass']
      },
      css: {
        files: ['fivesixtwo.com/src/FiveSixTwo.com/wwwroot/css/main.css'],
        tasks: []
      },
      scripts: {
        files: ['fivesixtwo.com/src/FiveSixTwo.com/wwwroot/js/site.js'],
        tasks: ['uglify']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your watch config:

```
scripts: {
    files: ['fivesixtwo.com/src/FiveSixTwo.com/wwwroot/js/site.js'],
    tasks: ['uglify']
}
```

You are only watching for a single js files changes called `site.js`. To watch all your sources use this config:

```
scripts: {
    files: ['fivesixtwo.com/src/FiveSixTwo.com/wwwroot/lib/*.js'],
    tasks: ['uglify']
}
```

Use the same pattern as in the uglify config. I assumed you are not going to modify jquery itself.

Comment: Yep, that was totally it. Wow. How does the brain get to a state where it just can't get past something no matter how simple the solution is?

In my head, it should have worked the way I had it because I'm generating a single JS file, and I'm just watching _it_ for changes. It appears that's how the CSS one is working.

It's watching that file, and running 'uglify' which should run the uglify task and bundle my js files. Now I see that's not how it works. It's still a bit confusing but at least I know how it's *supposed* to be set up. ;)

I _really_ hope this helps someone else!